# Regex for "Some Words [word] (foo@bar.com)"

Tags: php, regex

I'm struggling with a regex (php 7.3) that will grab these:

```
Static Words [word] (foo@bar.com)
RE: Static Words [word] (foo@bar.com)
FW: Static Words [word] (foo@bar.com)
FW: FW: Static Words [word] (foo@bar.com)
```

I can get it generically with:

```
/.*?(\[.*?\]).*?(\(.*\))/is
```

But I would like it to search for "Static Words" and then any alpha numeric string in the square brackets and then an email address in the round brackets, specifically.

Note that their may be text in from of "Static Words" as this is an email subject line, could be forwarded or replied to.

This is what I've ultimately come up with, looking for feedback:

```
/^(.*?)Static\h+Words\h+\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\][^()]+\(([^@\s]+@[^@\s.]+\.[^@\s]+)\)$/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this gets it:

```
/^(.*?)Static\h+Words\h+\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\][^()]+\(([^@\s]+@[^@\s.]+\.[^@\s]+)\)$/
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you might want to design an expression, somewhat similar to:

```
(?is)([^[]+?)\s*\[([a-z0-9]*)\]\s*\(([^@]+@[^.]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,6})\)
```

with more or less boundaries, not sure though.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/NmBBoJ/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/NmBBoJ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?is)([^[]+?)\s*\[([a-z0-9]*)\]\s*\(([^@]+@[^.]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,6})\)/';
$str = 'Some Words [word] (foo@bar.com)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "Some Words [word] (foo@bar.com)"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Some Words"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "word"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "foo@bar.com"
  }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Very complete, thank you. However, I needed to clarify a bit (see original post).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match "Some words", alphanumeric string and an email address like format you could use:

```
^Some\h+Words\h+\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\][^()]+\(([^@\s]+@[^@\s.]+\.[^@\s]+)\)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Some\h+Words\h+` Match "Some Words" where \h+ is one or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]` Match `[`....`]` and in between capture in group 1 matching 1+ times an alphanumeric char
- `[^()]+` Match 1+ times not `(` or `)` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `[^@\s]+@[^@\s.]+\.[^@\s]+` Match an "email like" format
- `)` Close group
- `\)` Match `)`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EC2eW0/1)

**Edit**

If you want to match all "words" and the match should not start with a space, you might use a repeating pattern to match 1+ non whitespace chars followed by 1+ horizontal whitespace chars `(?:\S+\h+)`

```
^(?:\S+\h+)+\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\][^()]+\(([^@\s]+@[^@\s.]+\.[^@\s]+)\)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pXkqee/1)

Comment: This was closer to what I wanted, thank you! I edited my post for clarification.